# Transforming an ellipse

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find an integral over the positive quadrant of the ellipse

$\frac {x^2}{a^2}+ \frac {y^2}{b^2}= 1$

by transforming the variables

$ x= a\sin \theta \cos \phi $

$ y= a\sin \theta \sin \phi $

Thing is, I'm getting confused when trying to find the limits in the new variables. If I substitute the transformation into the equation of the ellipse, I get

$\sin^2 \theta = 1$

So how do I find the limits I should be integrating with?

Comment: You should in fact get (for $0<\theta\le \frac {\pi}2$) $\;\displaystyle\frac {x^2}{a^2}+ \frac {y^2}{b^2}= \sin(\theta)^2\le 1$ (you are integrating over a surface not the border) and your double-integral should be over $(0,\frac {\pi}2)$ for $\theta$ as well as over $(0,\frac {\pi}2)$ for $\phi$.

Comment: Ah right thanks I was just able to visualise how the pieces add up

Comment: Fine! The limits for $\phi$ come from the first quadrant and concerning $\theta$ well $\sin(\theta)$ is a (kind of) radius for ellipsis (from $0$ to $1$). Note that you can provide yourself an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the way I visualise it is that

$ a\sin \theta $ and $ b \sin \theta $ are sort of analogous to $ r$ in polar coordinates. So the area is swept out along this radial direction as we go from $\theta=0$ to $\theta=\pi/2$. In the angular direction the first quadrant is swept out from $\phi=0$ to $\phi=\pi/2$